# Is it possible to write notepad++ plugin for tooltip on mouseover of text?

Tags: plugins, notepad++, mouseover

I have a text file with a list of registers, and I want to write a notepad++ plugin where the user can mouseover one of these registers (text), and a tooltip window pops up which contains information about the register.

I know that notepad++ supports c# and python plugins, and I understand that this type of functionality may be possible in javascript, but I am unsure if notepad++ plugins can be written in javascript, or if this functionality is even possible with a notepad++ plugin.

Sorry that I do not have any code to show, I am very new to writing notepad++ plugins, and so before embarking on this adventure I wanted to verify that this endeavor was even possible.  Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK all Npp plugins are dll written in C or C++

Comment: There is also Python Script plugin which allows you to write python programs that can run as macros and be assigned to menu entries or buttons.  I don't know yet if they can be triggered by mouseover, but I'm looking into it now...